# remove class from current group

Tags: javascript, jquery

The easiest way to see the problem is checking the code here: http://www.studioimbrue.com/beta

What I need to do is once a thumbnail is clicked, to removed the "selected" class from all other thumbnails that are in this same  or  without removing them from the other galleries on the page. Right now, I have everything working except the class removal. Someone helped me in another question but wasn't quite specific enough (my javascript skills aren't all that great!) I'm using jQuery. Thanks for the help.

Well in that case, I'm not sure why this doesn't work properly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var activeOpacity   = 1.0,
        inactiveOpacity = 0.6,
        fadeTime = 100,
        clickedClass = "selected",
        thumbs = ".thumbscontainer ul li img";

    $(thumbs).fadeTo(1, inactiveOpacity);

    $(thumbs).hover(
        function(){
            $(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
        },
        function(){
            // Only fade out if the user hasn't clicked the thumb
            if(!$(this).hasClass(clickedClass)) {
                $(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, inactiveOpacity);
            }
        });
     $(thumbs).click(function() {
         // Remove selected class from any elements other than this
         var previous = $(thumbs+'.'+clickedClass).eq();
         var clicked = $(this);
         if(clicked !== previous) {
             previous.removeClass(clickedClass);
         }
         clicked.addClass(clickedClass).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using jQuery (and have edited your question accordingly).

With jQuery, it's really easy to get a list of matching elements using CSS syntax:

```
var list = $('#parentId > .selected');
```

That gets a list of the direct children of the element with the ID "parentId" that have the class "selected". You can then do things with them, such as:

```
list.removeClass("selected");
```

Then add "selected" to the element you want to select.

**Edit** I think this should do it:

```
$(thumbs).click(function() {
     // Remove selected class from any elements other than this
     var clicked, previous;
     clicked = $(this);
     if (!clicked.hasClass(clickedClass)) {
         previous = $(thumbs+'.'+clickedClass);
         previous.removeClass(clickedClass).fadeTo(fadeTime, inactiveOpacity);
         clicked.addClass(clickedClass).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
     }
 });
```

I'm assuming there that the "selected" class isn't necessary for the fade effect to look right.

Note how the above will completely ignore the click if the clicked element already has the class. If you don't want that, remove the `hasClass` check and add `.not(clicked)` to the end of the `previous = $(thumbs+'.'+clickedClass)` line, but I don't know what your fade in would do at that point if you've already done it once.

I'm not getting the hover stuff; I thought you wanted this to happen on click, not hover.

Comment: This seems most close to what I need, but I can't quite get it to work... could you put it in context in the code above? I tried this:


         var previous = $(thumbs + '.' + clickedClass).eq();
   var list = $('#list li .selected');
         var clicked = $(this);
         if(clicked !== previous) {
             list.removeClass(clickedClass);
         }
         clicked.addClass(clickedClass).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
     });


but the thumbs still don't fade out after clicking a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at

[jQuery.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

So the point would be to first iterate trough all the images and unset the classname and than set the class on the active one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.closest('.jcarousel-clip')` to get the parent div, 
then find all the thumbnails and use `.removeClass('selected')`.

Comment: As I said, I'm really bad at javascript! Thanks all for the help, but I don't really know how to put these into context as my skills are limited to a very short number of things. I've had help from a javascript friend all the way so that's the only reason some of the scripts that are in there are functioning properly.

I added the current script that I have set up.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Andy it isn't clear your question, but I am going to try to help you.
I am trying to help, and my skills on javascript arent that good either, plus I am not sure if I undertood the question right, please, dont vote me down.

```
     function focusme(){
         document.getElementById("focusme").focus();
       }
     function changeToCurrent(obj){
         var menucont = document.getElementById('menu');
         var arrLink = menucont.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0 ; i &lt; arrLink.length; i++){
             arrLink[i].className=''; 
          }
          obj.className = "current";
         }



<div class="menu" id="menu" >
     <a  href='' id='focusme' onclick='changeToCurrent(this)'>link1</a>
     <a  href='' onclick='changeToCurrent(this)'>Once Only link2</a>
     <a  href='' onclick='changeToCurrent(this)'>link3</a>
     <a  href='' onclick='changeToCurrent(this)'>link4</a>
     <a  href='' onclick='changeToCurrent(this)'>link5</
     <a href="">link6</a>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The thing is that the list I have set up for the thumbnails follows a current setup already using <ul> and <li> and I want to avoid onclicks and in-line coding.